# Does any one know a better way to get the handle of an opened popup window?

Tags: javascript, popup

**Problem:**   Need to get a handle of an already opened javascript popup window (handle = window.open(…)) from its opener window, multiple requests later after its opener (parent) window has been refreshed and javascript variables reset.

For example, parent window could have javascript as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var popupHandle;
      function openPopUp() {
            popupHandle=window.open('http://www.google.ca', 'popupTest');
            popupHandle.focus();
            return popupHandle;
      }
      // To get handle, need to reopen popup with same name as original (popupTest).
      function getPopUpHandle() {
            return openPopUp();
      }
      // If getting handle to close, open as small as possible and close so it’s not too noticeable.
      function closePopUp() {
            popupHandle=window.open('', 'popupTest', 'directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,titlebar=no,top=1,left=1,width=1,height=1');
            popupHandle.close();
      }
</script>
```

If you know of a better solution, please let me know.

**How I am using it in my app:**
I have a list of images displayed on one side of the screen.
On the other side I have a form that allows me to submit information based on the image. When the form is submitted, it attaches the image referenced.

When an image is clicked on, it opens in a popup.

When the form is submitted, the next image in the list should open in the popup.
The popup could have been closed by the user.

Comment: Not an answer, but popups are bad, don't use them :) Try solutions like lightbox that might give your user a better experience.

Comment: The reason that a popup (which I think are bad as well) is used is so that the user can view the image in a separate window/monitor while filling in the form, using it as a reference. The images may need to be expanded to full screen at times to view the details.

Comment: wouldn't lightbox fit your needs ? http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: I may not be looking at lightbox correctly. I need to be able to open an image, view it on one monitor, view the list of images and a form on the main page, and enter details of the opened image into the form. When I submit the form, the next image in the list should be opened in the same popup. With lightbox, as the images open, they cannot be moved to another monitor, and the page itself is hidden. Or am I missing some options with it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a kludge, but you could put a script in the *opened* window that attempts to call a function on its window.opener to inform the parent window of its existence.

So, the image-display window would have a function like

```
setInterval(function(){ 
   if(window.opener.registerChildWindow){ 
        window.opener.registerChildWindow(window);
   } 
 }), 100);
```

This would attempt call the `registerChildWindow` function on the parent window 10 times a second, as long as that function exists, no matter what page the parent window was on. I'm not entirely sure how to get a window handle out of an existing window (passing `window` was a guess), but that should at least be something to play around with.